# WebGL `uniform uint` Causes Syntax Error

Tags: glsl, webgl, vertex-shader, glsles

I am using Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

I have a vertex shader that looks like so:

```
attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoordinate;

uniform uint uLayer;
uniform vec2 uLocation;

varying highp vec2 vTextureCoordinate;

void main(void)
{
  gl_Position = vec4(aPosition + vec3(uLocation, 0.0), 1.0);
  vTextureCoordinate = aTextureCoordinate;
}
```

A prior version did not have line four (`uniform unit uLayer;`), and it compiled fine. Adding in that line causes an `ERROR: 0:5: 'uLayer' : syntax error`. As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with this line syntactically, and I cannot find anything stating `uniform uint` is not valid in a vertex shader. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: uint don't exist in glsl 100, only int. You have it in glsl 300 (webgl2)

Comment: Ah. Thanks - I should have thought to check the GLSL version specified in WebGL. If you want to add that as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL 1 uses GLSL 100, which does not support `uint`. WebGL 2 uses GLSL 300 which adds `uint`.